# Runspace Analysis

Tags: algorithm, runtime, estimation, runspace

Is there any materials I can read on run space analysis of an algorithm +O, +Theta , +Omega etc ? Need help for a Data Structures and Algorithm class I am taking.

Answer (score 1):

Check out chapter eight of Michael Sipser, Introduction to the Theory of Computation. A great chapter from a great book.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

[Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937)

[image]

It's what most computer science undergraduates have to read inorder to understand runtime complexity theory.

Comment: He said run space, not run time. I don't really like that book, so I could be wrong, but I don't think it talks about run space complexity at all.

Comment: I've never heard of space complexity being separately treated from runtime complexity - but I could be wrong.  The Leaf book is considered the gold standard for this kind of stuff though...

Comment: It's true that you don't talk about space complexity without talking about time complexity, but it's perfectly possible to talk about time complexity without talking about space complexity. I think that is the case with this book (I don't have a copy to check; I ditched mine a long time ago. I think CLRS is highly overrated.)

Answer (score 0):

Its the gold standard but the puedocode approach it uses to decribe the algorithms is dated. Most indiviuals are better able to understand simple C or javascript type statements than the puedocode approach that the book uses.